# AWS API Gateway returns 200 with response but later returns 200 with no response

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, httpcookie

I am running into an issue with an API Gateway/Lambda implementation. I've written a authentication service that works across subdomains and appears to work fine in most cases. Testing locally works perfect.

When it is deployed to AWS, with the API in a Lambda with an API Gateway in front of it, the log in system works great. The user can login, which returns a 200 and then a ReturnClaims-style endpoint returns their access, and other useful account bits.

The problem arises that after a little while (like an hour or so usually) the ReturnClaims endpoint will continue to return a 200 but the response is now empty when the page is refreshed.

The HTTP-Only cookie still lives in the browser and it's not throwing any errors.

When running locally, this issue doesn't arise at all. The user can refresh for as long as the cookie has and JWT has been instructed to last (which is 30 days but I've adjusted this for testing purposes as needed).

I am hoping someone might have an idea of what might cause an endpoint on AWS to function in this manner, perhaps some life setting I am unaware of?

I appreciate any advice or suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: are you making any async calls from the lambda , you might not be waiting for any promises to resolve. if you can't figure out, please post some code

Comment: From what I have been able to determine, we are waiting for all async calls to finish. Locally when I debug the code everything works great, and the initial calls work great on AWS, it's just the ones after a rough time period that it fails which is why it's suspect. I'll see what I can post and hopefully identify which its are relevant. Thanks!

Comment: it sounds like a lambda cold start issue to me, and also it feels to me that somewhere some code is not waiting for an async call to finish.